Cannot translate EF Core linq query (change SRID of point)
In the code below, I was trying to get geographic points from the database and filter them based on the distance to the user.
var pointQueryable = DbContext.Points.OrderBy(x => x.Title).AsNoTracking();
var userPoint = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(filter.UserLongitude, filter.UserLatitude) { SRID = 4326 };

pointQueryable = pointQueryable.Where(x => userPoint.Distance(x.Location) < (filter.MaxDistance));

But the output of the Distance method was degrees and not meters.
I again tried to change the SRID using the following method to get the output of the meter:
// this from Microsoft...
public static Geometry ProjectTo(this Geometry geometry, int srid)
{
    var transformation = _coordinateSystemServices.CreateTransformation(geometry.SRID, srid);

    var result = geometry.Copy();

    result.Apply(new MathTransformFilter(transformation.MathTransform));

    return result;
}

And I use it like this:
pointQueryable = pointQueryable.Where(x => userPoint.ProjectTo(3857).Distance(x.Location.ProjectTo(3857)) < (filter.MaxDistance));

But I get an error that says:

The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
.OrderBy(g => g.Title)
.Where(g => g.Location
.ProjectTo(3857).Distance(__ProjectTo_0) < __filter_MaxDistance_1)'   > could not be translated.

Of course, I received some suggestions and solutions, one of them was to do the filters after running the query and ToListAsync.
But I think that the speed of responding to the request will increase and users will expect more.

Instead of using ProjectTo, try EF.Functions.Transform(geom, srid)

Thank you very much! This works well, But I don't know why when I enter the same points with the points stored in the database, instead of returning 0, it returns a larger value (for example, about 22 km).
I saw the blue screen more than twice today, I think it is from the codes I wrote. lol

You are using geometry not geography, it's the wrong type.

Thanks, but I had already set the field as geography, but I was getting the error 42883: function st_x(geography) does not exist.
